# Filter the returned elements in an array after a mongodb query

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

If I understood correctly this is called a `projection` in mongodb. I have seen that there are two types of useful projections operators: `elemMatch` and `$`.

I have a set of documents that each have a list of attributes(Object). I want to perform complex queries to match these attributes namely matching several of its fields(using `regex`, etc).

Right now when a document matches a query the Java driver is returning the whole document. I want to filter it to just return the attributes which matched the original query.

I have tried combining `elemMatch` but all I was able to accomplish was returning either all attributes or just one(normally the first match).

Mongo document structure as below :

```
    {
    "name": "MediaPlayer",
    "attributes": [
        {
            "tag": "media",
            "values": [
                "mp3",
                "mp4"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "teste",
            "values": [
                "teste"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and my query as :

```
{attributes : {$elemMatch: { 'tag' : 'media'},$elemMatch: { 'tag' : 'stream'}}}
```

and it return following results :

```
{
    "name": "MediaStream",
    "attributes": [
        {
            "tag": "media",
            "values": [
                "Edit"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "stream",
            "values": [
                "Edit"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "video",
            "values": [
                "Edit"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The example and returned are different documents. Although I matched `two` attributes I got the whole list returned.

I wanted the attributes array to contain only the matched elements.

How would I be able to do this?

**EDIT:**

From what I have seen the mongodb find operation does not support internal array filtering. There are some examples using the mongodb aggregation framework. Other than that doing the filtering manually seems like the only possible way.

Comment: Can you show us some sample documents, the code you have tried and expected results?

Comment: @chridam Done. If anything else is needed please do say.

Comment: @Saraiva  `$elemMatch` having limitation like it only return  the first element matching the `$elemMatch` condition, if you run this query `{"attributes":{"$elemMatch":{"tag":"media"}},"attributes":{"$elemMatch":{"tag":"teste"}}},{"attributes.$.tag":1}` it return only one matching array not whole array , so if you want to find out all matching array then should use mongo aggregation

Comment: @yogesh I understand how i can get it by using techniques like unwind. However, i do not control the querys. I am trying to find a way to, somehow, understand which attributes are successfully being matches without having any prior knowledge to the query content. I am yet to find an aggregation that can do that. I can elaborate why i think aggregation may not work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you want to match `tag:media` and `tag:stream`, this case you entered your matching criteria in [mongo $in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) aggregation query as below

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
"$unwind": "$attributes" // first unwind attributes array 
}, {
"$match": {
  "attributes.tag": {
    "$in": ["media", "stream"] // put all matching tags in array using $in
  }
}
}, {
"$group": {
  "_id": "$_id",
  "name": {
    "$first": "$name"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "$push": "$attributes" // push all attributes to get only matching tags
  }
}
}).pretty()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help. I realized i have to constraint the query input and do something like that. Later ill update with a full solution and description.

Answer (score 1):

Found a possible solution : [Solution A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220910/how-to-return-just-the-matched-elements-from-a-mongodb-array?rq=1)

EDIT: The aggregation found does not prove to offer a general solution to the problem since i am not controlling the queries. In this sense, if i want to unwind the attributes and then match it against the query it will only work on queries matching a single attribute.

Comment: As per my understand I think you want to match two tags in unwind like `tag:media` and `tag:stream` ? and you not able to write aggregation query right?

Comment: @yogesh From a unknown query (Not created by me) i want to, in case a document is matched, know which of the registered attributes gave a positive match. For instance, if i have a document with 10 attributes and a query matched 7. I want to have the query return the full document with only the 7 matched attributes. Thus, this is a case of a filtered array.